# Call application(which is added as non-executable jar in consumer project) method automatically while starting consumer application

Tags: java

I am working on a library project which is in java and it's jar will be used further by any other applications. My requirement is, On starting of consumer application(which will use my library as jar), I have to automatically call one method of added jar application without explicitly calling it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's get the point of meaning "implicit calling":

> Implicit calling is function calling which is made by the compiler automatically without user's interference.

So you have to call a method which is managed by JVM. For example creation of class instance by default constructor would be an implicitly call.

```java
// let an Obj be in a jar
class Obj {
    private int a = 1;
    public String toString () { return (a); }
}

Obj o = new Obj();  // implicitly calling
System.out.println(o) // implicitly calling, java will call toString() by itself
System.out.println(o.toString()) // explicitly calling
```

Comment: Thanks Andrii for taking your time. However, I want to perform certain operations in jar by starting up main application which is using that jar. I can neither call implicitly nor explicitly.Since I don't want to write any code in client application which is using my jar everything should be in my jar.

Comment: @NandiniNandini now it's hard for me to understand the point of the question. What do certain operations mean?  If you want to execute some code at the start of your jar simply use blocks or static blocks that are executing earlier than other code and even constructors.